# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'networkSecurityConfig' with value '@xml/network_security_config')

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm beginner developer in ionic.
I tried to "ionic cordova run android --device" command to run app on my phone.

fell into error below ('sample' is my project.)

> :processDebugResources
> /Users/xxx/sample/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml:33:53-81: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'networkSecurityConfig' with value '@xml/network_security_config').
> /Users/xxx/sample/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/xml/config.xml:33: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'networkSecurityConfig' with value '@xml/network_security_config').

so, I did below action.

1. edit config.xml file to set real AndroidManifest.xml location.
   (app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml -> AndroidManfest.xml)

- (before)
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl8Pk.png)
- (after)
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TN1q.png)

2. in my AndoridManifest.xml set minSdkVersion="16" and targetSdkVersion="26".

Any help would be appreciated. :)

PS) ionic info is...

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.5
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.9
```

System:

```
Node  : v6.11.3
npm   : 3.10.10 
OS    : macOS
Xcode : Xcode 12.4 Build version 12D4e
```

Answer (score 4):

it solved by edit config.xml file like this:

> target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" -> target="res/xml/network_security_config.xml"